# CSS background-image url not getting url

Tags: css

```
image(imageurl){
  return "http://web.com/"+imageurl+".jpg";
```

How to use this url in CSS background-image ?

here is css

```
<div style="width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url ('image(post.postimage)');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;">
</div>
```

Comment: That's not how you write CSS.

Comment: Is this your css!!

Comment: It's not CSS in any kind. What are you using?

Comment: Cascading JavaScript Sheets

Answer (score 2):

CSS background-image

```
.class_name{
    background-image: url("image path");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The CSS syntax to define a background image is

```
#element {
  background-image: url('path/to/file.jpg');
  /* Only for demonstration: */
  width = 50%; 
  height = 50%;
}
```

where element is the object-id in your html document

```
<div id='element'></div>
```

**Edit**

In your code

```
background-image: url ('image(post.postimage)');
```

remove the **' '**, otherwise the function is not being called, but instead passed as a file path (to a non-existing location).